# Was Daeron Targaryen married?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the chapter *The Kingbreaker* of *A Dance with Dragons* Barristan Selmy thinks:

> All three of the sons of the fifth Aegon had wed for love, in defiance of their father’s wishes.

While I can find evidence that the two oldest  sons Duncan and Jaehaerys II did it seems that Daeron never did. Then why did Selmy think this?

Comment: Arrrrghh... why did GRRM create *two* Daeron-son-of-Aegons... For anyone else getting confused reading this question, like I did, *this* Daeron-son-of-Aegon was a son of Egg (AKA Aegon V, "the Unlikely"), and was never king. Not to be confused with Daeron-II-son-of-Aegon-IV ("the Unworthy"), the Blackfyre-Rebellion-fighting Daeron, who was Egg's granddad... too many Targaryens with the same darn name!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No, but like his older brothers, he didn't wed as his father wished.

From [a Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daeron_Targaryen_%28son_of_Aegon_V%29), sourced to *The World of Ice and Fire*:

> When both were nine years old, Prince Daeron was betrothed to Lady Olenna Redwyne in 237 AC, a betrothal arranged by Daeron's mother. After his three older siblings, Duncan, Jaehaerys and Shaera had broken their own betrothals - Duncan to marry Jenny of Oldstones, Jaehaerys and Shaera to marry each other - Daeron broke his betrothal to Olenna as well. He did so when he was eighteen years old, in 246 AC. But while his brothers had broken their betrothals for another woman, this was not the case for Daeron.
>
> While Daeron would not live for much longer, he would remain unwed.

Duncan and Jaehaerys did marry for love - [Duncan](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Duncan_Targaryen) breaking his betrothal to a Baratheon girl in order to marry the "strange, lovely, and mysterious" peasant woman [Jenny of Oldstones](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jenny_of_Oldstones), and [Jaehaerys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_II_Targaryen) following directly in his older brother's footsteps, breaking his own betrothal to [Celia Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Celia_Tully) in order to marry his sister [Shaera](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Shaera_Targaryen).

I don't know the context of the quote you mention, but what Barristan Selmy *should* have thought was:

> All three of the sons of the fifth Aegon had failed to fulfil their betrothal agreements, in defiance of their father’s wishes.

Instead Selmy tarred Daeron (incorrectly) with the same brush as the older two, who did so in order to wed different women for the sake of love. Daeron did not; in fact, as Olenna Redwyne herself tells Sansa in *A Storm of Swords*, chapter 6, it was she who ended the betrothal and not Daeron.

Comment: Final sentence conflicts somewhat with the premise of your answer.

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister Fixed.